# How to keep Django from escaping HTML in ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have this class to configure `django.contrib.admin` for my `Stream` model.

```
class StreamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def stream_title(instance):
        return instance.info.title

    def network_name(instance):
        return '<img src="%s" />' % instance.network.image_url

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields' : ('name', 'network', 'score', 'custom_url')
        }),

    )

    list_display = ('name', stream_title, network_name, 'online', 'score')

    ordering = ('name', 'score')
```

The network_name function returns HTML, but it's escaped. How can I stop that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `allow_tags`.

```
def network_name(instance):
    return '<img src="%s" />' % instance.network.image_url
network_name.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: Since django 1.9 the allow_tags is deprecated, so use `mark_safe()`, `format_html()` or `format_html_join()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe):

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class StreamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def network_name(instance):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" />' % instance.network.image_url)

    ...
```

Try using [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#std%3atemplatefilter-safe) filter at the template or even [autoescape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#autoescape).

Using the autoescape tag you can set up a block like this:

```
{% autoescape on %}
    {{ model.network_name }}
{% endautoescape %}

<!-- or either -->
{{ model.network_name|safe }}
```

Comment: Changed my line to `return mark_safe('<img src="%s" />' % instance.network.image_url)` but it still escapes the HTML

Comment: I've incremented my answer, but that's odd that mark_safe didn't work.

Comment: `mark_safe` is appropriate for your own views, but in the django admin, `allow_tags` is the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't know that :/